# Display data from List in C#

Tags: c#, database, list

I would like to display the data which I get from List when the result of my List is = to 1. I need to get the `FileName`, `Title` and `HotspotID`.

Can somebody help me with it? The part that I need help is at the end part of my code.

here is the code:

```
    private void PerformSheetLink(String hotspotID, Int32 fileRec)
    {
        string nomenclature = dataLayer.GetNomenclature(fileRec, hotspotID);
        string pattern = @"\((?<ProjectRec>\d+(?:_)?\d*?)*\,(?<FileName>[^,]*)\,(?<HotspotID>[^)]*)\)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        Match m = regex.Match(nomenclature);

        //Multiple numenclature exist           
        if (regex.Matches(nomenclature).Count > 1)
        {
            List<P2Trace> linkList = new List<P2Trace>();
            string fileName, hotspot, title;                
            MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(nomenclature);
            foreach (Match match in mc)
            {
                //This match has a Single Project
                GroupCollection gc = match.Groups;
                if (gc["ProjectRec"].Captures.Count == 1)
                {
                    if ((int)cbModel.SelectedValue == Int32.Parse(gc["ProjectRec"].Value))
                    {
                        fileName = String.Format("{0}.cgm", gc["FileName"].Value);
                        title = dataLayer.GetSheetTitle(fileName);
                        hotspot = FixHotspotID(gc["HotspotID"].Value);
                        linkList.Add(new P2Trace { FileName = fileName, HotspotID = hotspot, Title = title });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //This match has Multiple Projects 
                    List<Int32> pRecs = GetProjectRecsInList(gc["ProjectRec"].Captures);
                    if (pRecs.Contains((int)cbModel.SelectedValue))
                    {
                        foreach (Int32 projectRecNo in pRecs)
                        {
                            if (projectRecNo == (int)cbModel.SelectedValue)
                            {
                                fileName = String.Format("{0}.cgm", gc["FileName"].Value);
                                title = dataLayer.GetSheetTitle(fileName);
                                hotspot = FixHotspotID(gc["HotspotID"].Value);
                                linkList.Add(new P2Trace { FileName = fileName, HotspotID = hotspot, Title = title });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Link found and collected, perform jump
            if (linkList.Count == 1)
            {
               p2Trace.FileName = linkList. ?????
               p2Trace.Title = linkList. ??????
               p2Trace.HotspotID= linkList. ??????
               jumpTo(p2Trace.FileName, p2Trace.Titel, p2Trace.HotspotID);

            }
```

Comment: Is it your intent to only call the `jumpTo` if you find exactly one match? What should happen if you found two matches?

Comment: I already took care of that part, i just didn't post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p2Trace.FileName = linkList[0].FileName;
p2Trace.Title = linkList[0].Title;
p2Trace.HotspotID = linkList[0].HotspotID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    if (linkList.Count == 1)
    {
var firstItem = linkList[0];
       p2Trace.FileName = firstItem.FileName;
       p2Trace.Title = firstItem.Title;
       p2Trace.HotspotID= firstItem.HostspotID;
       jumpTo(p2Trace.FileName, p2Trace.Titel, p2Trace.HotspotID);

    }
```